# Substitution method for exact differential equation help

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to use the substitution method to solve for a differential equation. The equation is

$y'=(x+y-3)^2 $, $ y(0) = 0$

I used substitution to get $u=x+y-3$ and $u'=1+y'$. So the final equation is $$u'-1=u^2$$ However, I am unsure how to get the final y= equation with the initial value included. I would really appreciate someone's help on how to solve.

Comment: Solve the ode in $u$ using the separation of variables techniques first. Then subs. $u=x+y-3$.

Answer (score 0):

After rearranging, the equation is separable:

$$u' = u^2 + 1 \implies \frac{u'}{u^2 + 1} = 1 \implies \int \frac{u'(x)}{u(x)^2 + 1} dx = \int dx$$

The left-hand integral is then simply $\arctan u$.